# Select 2 lowest values from a query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying get information of 2 lowest salary holders from default "scott" table.

This is the query I am trying:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM emp ORDER BY sal ASC
```

But I'm getting this error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Oracle does not have a `TOP` keyword to get the first n rows.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson then what should I use?

Comment: @MT0 thank you. I got the solution.

Comment: @Md.ShohanHossain I know, but it doesn't stop the question being a duplicate and it is more valuable to other people to link to the other question with much more detailed answers.

Comment: @MT0 don't worry. I am marking this question as duplicate. I didn't find the answer when I search for it. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most recent versions of Oracle, you can use the ANSI standard:

```
SELECT emp.*
FROM emp
ORDER BY sal ASC
FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

In older versions:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT emp.*
      FROM emp
      ORDER BY sal ASC
     ) e
WHERE rownum <= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks! 2nd one works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROWNUM in Oracle to get two first rows of your query results.

```
SELECT EMP1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM EMP ORDER BY SAL ASC) EMP1 WHERE ROWNUM < 3;
```

Comment: It works. (y)Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- TOP X is used by SQL Server
- Fetch first is used by Oracle and DB2
  (rownum is also available in Oracle)
- Limit is used by mysql
- Many can also use a windowing function (`ROW_NUMBER()`) in a sub query.

You want

```
select * from emp ORDER BY sal ASC
fetch first 2 rows only
```

Comment: Thank you for these valuable information. :)

Comment: @Md.ShohanHossain - yw -- good luck